# File Permissioning Error for Apache on Linux

Tags: php, linux, apache, permissions

I'm trying to get a simple PHP file to work on a linux Centos 7 server using apache. The problem is that the php code doesn't seem to have permission to write to the folder. The simple test php file below illustrates the problem

```
<?php 
echo shell_exec('whoami');
echo "<br>";
$myfile = fopen("test.txt","w") or die("could not open test file");
fclose($myfile);
?>;
```

Just to try to get it to work I have done

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx /var/www
```

and yet I keep getting the "could not open test file" error message. What am I doing wrong? Incidentally, the 'whoami' is coming back as 'apache'

**Edit*

In the light of the suggestion below I've done some changes and am now showing the full permissioning for the folders. I've created the group www-data and have added the user apache to it.

```
[prompt]$ groups apache
apache : apache www-data
```

For /var/www:

```
0 drwxrwsrwx.  4 root www-data   33 Jul 27 08:19 www
```

For /var/www/html:

```
0 drwxrwsrwx.  2 root www-data 137 Jul 27 12:43 html
```

The file I'm trying to load:

```
4 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 root        www-data      182 Jul 27 12:40 test.php
```

It's still not working unfortunately. Might it be something in the apache configuration? Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options you can try

**Option 1**

Make sure the group is www-data on '/var/www'.

```
prompt> sudo chgrp www-data /var/www
```

Make '/var/www' writable for the group.

```
prompt> sudo chmod 775 /var/www
```

Set the GID for www-data for all sub-folders.

```
prompt> sudo chmod g+s /var/www
```

Your directory should look like this on an 'ls -l' output.

drwxrwsr-x

Last, add your user name to the www-data group (secondary group).

```
prompt> sudo useradd -aG www-data [USERNAME]
```

**Option 2**

Use the *mod_userdir* as described in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_userdir.html

I would recommend the first option as it suits your needs better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but it's still not working. I've edited my original question in the light of your suggestions and have given a full print-out of the permissions for the folders and the file in question.